# Java android eclipse, starting activity in thread: application stopped working

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

Hey I am doing a simple Android app and I am trying to a start new activity from a thread like this:

```
 public void startUI (){
     Thread t = new Thread(){
         public void run () {
             runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Intent goToMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(goToMenu);
                }
            });
        ;}
     };
 t.start;
}
```

But when my code comes to this line

```
Intent goToMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
```

It crashes and writes: "application stopped working".

Comment: Why do you require a thread in the first place.?

Comment: Does MainMenu extend Activity?

Comment: Because i need to delay it 1500ms but i got rid of that code

Comment: @FilipSúkeník You can use a handler for delay. By any chance are you displaying splash screen??

Comment: yes i am displaying splashscreen with a few animation and UI Threads

Comment: You don't have to use a thread to call an activity , and maybe there is something wrong with other parts of your code. you should post your Log cat.

Comment: but after this SplashScreen I want to change activity but normal way doesn't work

Comment: @FilipSúkeník don't use splash screen. Instead look at the design guidelines and show a branded screen or a place holder ui depending on how fast you have the ui rendered for the first screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start an activity you need to use `Activity` context as a first parameter. If you use `Application` context then your `MainMenu` activity must have a `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag set. You cannot start new activity in the same task from application context.

Refer: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

As @Raghunandan mentioned, if you want a delay, you should use a `Handler` like this:

```
uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent goToMenu = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
        goToMenu.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(goToMenu);
    }
}, 500);
```